# Tor Browser says Firefox is already running

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

When I launch `Start Tor Browser.exe` it indicates that the circuit is established but then immediately gives the following error message:

> Firefox is already running, but not responding. To open a new window,
>   you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your
>   system.

This happens even though Firefox is not running. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is also happening to me - I have checked the task manager and there is no "firefox.exe" process running.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I've got that message, it's been because a Firefox process actually was running, even though there was no Firefox window.  Since it sounds like you're running Windows, have you tried Ctrl-Alt-Del to open the system manager and looked for a Firefox process?  If you find one, try killing it.

Comment: Firefox doesn't always shut down cleanly. If you can consistently reproduce this, perhaps you should file a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, though the firefox process was closed. Additionally if I tried to open TorBrowser parallel to normal Firefox it just opened another (normal) Firefox window. I had installed TorBrowser on C:\Program Files\Tor Browser. Try to extract the Tor Browser Bundle on another partition, on an external harddrive or an USB-stick. This worked in my case.

Comment: Firefox uses interprocess communication to control the running instance. This mechanism should not depend on where is the `firefox` executable file. I guess that there must be something different.

Comment: I have installed it in my D:\ drive and it seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is misleading, it hasn't to do with Firefox running. Because it needs write access to its own folder, Tor browser needs admin privileges when it's installed in Program Files folder. Either install the Tor bundle outside a system folder (such as c:\tools) or run it as Administrator (bad idea).